# Pass value to script without x=something

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, redirect, lighttpd, http-redirect

I'm writing a PHP script for link shortening.
I'm using Lighttpd, if that matters.
I have a folder "links" on the server with an "index.php" inside it.
I want to be able to use

```
http://www.site.com/links/thisisalinkid
```

and get that ID.

Apparently I can use mod_rewrite, but how do I do it if I have multiple domains pointing at my server with different document roots?  I want to run the script on a different domain than the default at /var/www.  How do I go about that?

Comment: mod_rewrite is your friend!  http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd2/wiki/Mod_rewrite/5

Comment: so you want to be able to query a particular route/script? Have your index.php use GET to get your your query parameter. The url will, as well, probably look like: `site.com/links?link=thisisantotherlink`

Comment: @CristianCavalli I can do your suggestion just fine, but that's not what I want.  I want to get a value without the key.  See my question.

Comment: @SkylarMT then use mod_rewrite, but you can't have an unkeyed get variable.